# How can I clone a display on a Pi 4?

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

I can successfully display across 2 monitors (extended desktop) but how can I clone instead of extend? I have been unable to find any resource helping me to achieve this.

This question for some reason has been put on hold as it seems to be "unclear". In an effort to make it more clear, here is what I want to achieve:

I want to mirror (clone) my desktop using the 2 HDMI outputs just like you can in Windows. The default behaviour is to extend which is not what I want.

Hope this is more clear now.

Comment: The default [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment#Desktop_environments_for_the_X_Window_System) (DE) used on Raspbian is a customized LXDE.  Lubuntu uses the same thing, so you might [have a look at this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/MultiDisplay) about the screen layout editor.

Comment: ...I can't promise that's in Raspbian, but it's a front end to `xrandr`, which is a command line tool that should work anywhere and is definitely available.  If you go down that path, questions are better off on our larger sibling site, [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).  You could instead install a more feature rich DE; the big ones such as KDE or GNOME will certainly have a simple GUI tool for configuring this. They may be a bit much on a Pi 4, so before that research XFCE.  Anyway, there are some places to start.

Comment: Personally I'd go for `xrandr`.  When you are searching for info/help about that (or most things, in fact), use "linux" instead of (not as well as) "raspberry pi".

Answer (score 2):

[From here:](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/127376/137108)

Open the Screen Layout Editor, drag HDMI2 on top of HDMI1, click the green checkbox, and done.