# Raspberry Pi 4 Dual Monitor Mirroring

Tags: pi-4

I have two of the exact same monitor on my Rpi4 up and running plugged into hdmi0 and hdmi1. It is extending the desktop, but I am looking for a way for them to mirror. I have tried searching all over, but either I get how to set it up the way I have it or making one of those magic mirrors. Is there a way to get my second monitor to mirror my first?

Answer (score 4):

I have to stop answering my own questions. Open the Screen Layout Editor, drag HDMI2 on top of HDMI1, click the green checkbox, and done.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Indeed the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case it's not working. It doesn't really mirror both screens, it makes something different and weird. Still 2 different screens doing different things and I can't find any other configuration to change that

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/133299)